# Unable to bind maven profile to spring boot profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-profiles, maven-profiles

**I've seen all the questions and post regarding this issue so please don't mark this as duplicate or route me to those issues, I have tried implementing those solutions but nothing worked as of now.**

I have profile specific application.properties files i.e `application-prod.properties, application-dev.properties, application-int.properties etc`

pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <activeProfile>prod</activeProfile>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>int</id>
        <properties>
            <activeProfile>int</activeProfile>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <activeProfile>dev</activeProfile>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    …
</build>
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.demo.Application</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>show-profiles</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>active-profiles</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    </plugins>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=@activeProfile@
```

I'm doing `mvn clean install -Pprod` and then running the application.
I'm sure the maven profile is executing during the build as I get this during the build

```
The following profiles are active:

 - prod (source: my-project-snapshot)
```

This is what I'm getting when running the application:

```
: The following profiles are active: @activeProfile@
```

Can anyone please help me here.

**UPDATE**
when I close my IDE(STS) and do the maven build, it is working. Any info regarding this info would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why do you like to have Maven profiles? Spring Boot profiles are different. Why do you need Maven profiles? Apart from that `application.profiles` is the profile which is called the `default` profile which means if no `--spring.profiles.active=xxx` is given. I don't understand why you need to filter your `application.properties` and replace the active profile option?

Comment: I don't want to manually input which profile I want to run the application everytime in `spring.profile.active` property in the **application.properties** file. What I want is spring boot to bind and run the application based on the profile passed during maven build

Comment: *run the application based on the profile passed during maven build* This explicitly goes against the way that profiles in Spring work, which is changing the runtime configuration of an *already compiled* application so that you can reuse the artifact. If your artifact changes based on a build parameter, you will need to cache up to X times the amount of artifacts, where X is the number of profiles you are building against. Why can you not simply use different IDE configurations/cmd line parameters? As an aside, `spring.profiles.active` should *not* be in your `application.properties`.

Comment: I'm not sure how _I'm changing the runtime configuration of an already compiled application_? I'm building my application with dev maven profile so I want the spring boot app to run it on the same profile, what's wrong here? I've seen various posts on these, everyone endorsed it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled resource filtering in your `pom.xml`? Since you are using spring-boot this can be easily enabled, in your `pom.xml`

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    …
</build>
```

**UPDATE**
I have put all your plugins in a sample project's `pom.xml` also matching your spring-boot version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>in.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <activeProfile>prod</activeProfile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <activeProfile>dev</activeProfile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>show-profiles</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>active-profiles</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <index>true</index>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.example.demo.DemoApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I run

```
mvn clean package spring-boot:run -Pdev -DskipTests
```

I see in the log files

```
com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : The following profiles are active: dev
```

And when I check the generated jar in `target` dir...`target\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\BOOT-INF\classes\` filtering has succeeded since in `application.properties` I get the line:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

which in the source `application.properties` is

```
spring.profiles.active=@activeProfile@
```

So if you have a pom file similar to the above filtering should work.

[image]

Comment: Ok can you share your full `pom.xml`? Also which version of spring-boot are you using?

Comment: I'm using spring boot v2.2.1.release. Regarding sending whole the pom.xml, it would be tricky as there are sensitive info in it. I would post the important bits from the pom in the question, will that be fine?

Comment: Are you using `spring-boot-starter-parent` as the parent of your `pom.xml`? Moreover are your `application-*.properties` inside `src/main/resources` or elsewhere?

Comment: Yes I do have `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent of my pom.xml and all my property files are inside  `src/main/resources`. I also have `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in my plugins.

Comment: Also please share all your plugins configuration in `pom.xml` maybe you are overriding something there e.g. if you have `maven-resources-plugin` configured and it fails to filter via spring-boot default mechanism.

Comment: I have edited my question and added the plugins config. Please have a look.

Comment: @user11423673 I have updated my answer please check carefully my pom.xml to spot any differences with yours, and also please share how you build your `jar`, which maven commands you use?

Comment: it's still not working, I even created a new project and implemented the code you have posted :(  I normally do `mvn clean install -P<profile>`.   I tried with this too-`mvn clean package spring-boot:run -Pdev -DskipTests`

Comment: when I run the app with a  default profile only then spring boot take the profile`<profile<id>prod</id<activation<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation><properties><activeProfile>prod</activeProfile></properties></profile>`

Comment: So you took my pom.xml without any changes, created a new project and still doesn't work? Very weird. Also `<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>` then it works which means that filtering works but somehow when passing from command line via `-P` though maven recognizes the profile, filtering doesn't work! ?!?!?!?!

Comment: Yes that is exactly what is happening!! And yes I implemented your pom without any changes  but it did not work :(. During the maven build process, I get `The following profiles are active:
 - dev (source: com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)` and when the app is running it shows `com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : The following profiles are active: @activeProfile@`

Comment: Very weird, I just uploaded a pic with a clean empty project I just re-created with my pom.xml. It has the bare minimum and when I run `mvn clean package -Pdev` you can see in the `target\classes\application.properties` the `@activeProfile@` has been substituted by `dev`. I am afraid I cannot help you further, if for the same project setup filtering is failing.

Comment: Oh btw have you checked your maven version? Could it be an old one and something is wrong with it? Mine is `3.6.0`

Comment: I finally found something interesting. When I'm closing the IDE and then running the command then it's working. Do you have any idea why is that?

Comment: Really? could it be that something got cached from your IDE? I can't know what it might be :)

Comment: Yes I think so too, may be it has something to do with the IDE because I tried deleting the .m2 folder and build it again from scratch, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @pleft, I tried everything and because of that I realized this may not be a maven issue but an IDE issue. I'm using STS 3 and I found out that disabling "**Refresh using native hooks**" under `Window > preferences > General > Workspace > Refresh using native hooks` would solve the issue of STS IDE ignoring `-P<profile>` during maven build when STS is open.

There seems to be already a [bug ticket](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=462027#c7) for this.